# How to take input from user for size of an array and array elements using dom in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, web-development-server

I am building a web project which will perform various sorting algorithms to sort an array. For this purpose, I want to take input from user for array size and also user input for array elements of the entered size. I am not getting the expected result by my code.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="screen-body-item">
    <div class="app-form">
    <div class="app-form-group">
    <input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter size" id="size">
    <input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter element" id="ele">
    <input type="button" value="" value="add value" class="app-form-button" onclick="addval()">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        function addval() {
            var inputArray = [];
            let size = document.getElementById('size').value;
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                inputArray[i] = document.getElementById('ele').value;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can either take all array values in a single input separated by `,` or you can create as many input elements as the user enters in the `size` ...

Comment: I want to know what is `size` is that like when user enter `size=5` and `value=apple` and you want to store value 5 time in an array eg: `["apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple"]`.

Comment: @Sparrow I want output like this..."Enter size of array: 5, enter 5 elements : 3 5 1 2 6" This elements(numbers) may be anything that user wants!

Comment: User can enter only numbers in element input?

Comment: What if user not enter same number of elements with size, will you show alert.

Comment: Ok wait. I will write one answer and we will change answer how you want.

Comment: @Sparrow Yes, user can enter only numbers. Yes if user will not entered numbers with given size then it will show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code looks little lengthy, because I have wirten function to type only number and space element in inputs. and added some filters.

Please try your self this code. If you can't understand somewhere please write comment below, I feel good to explain someone.

Please note: User only can enter numbers in inputs.

```js
let sizeInput = document.querySelector('#size');
let eleInput = document.querySelector('#ele');

// allow only numbers to type
[eleInput, sizeInput].forEach(input=>{
    input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let value = parseInt(event.key);

        if(!isNaN(value)) return input.value += value;
        if(input == eleInput && event.key == ' ') return input.value += event.key;
    });
});

// main function
function addval(event) {
    event?.preventDefault(); // if button is in form element
    let inputArray = [];

    let size = parseInt(sizeInput.value);
    let elements = eleInput.value;

    if(isNaN(size)) return alert('Please enter valid size.'); // stop and show alert if size is invalid or empty

    elements = elements.trim(); // remove space from starting and end
    elements = elements.replace(/  +/g, ' '); // remove multiple spaces
    elements = elements.split(' '); // split by space

    if(elements.length != size) return alert(`Please enter ${size < elements.length ? 'only': ''} ${size} elements`);

    inputArray = elements;

    console.log(inputArray); // remove later
    return inputArray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter size" id="size">
<input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter element" id="ele">
<input type="button" value="add value" class="app-form-button" onclick="addval()">
```

Comment: Also I have written some comments on code please check those.

Comment: Can you explain this statement, "event?.preventDefault();"

Comment: When you call `addval` function with event it will prevent defaults. It will help you when you write those inputs in `<form>` element. because when you submit form it will reload your website so, to prevent reloading your page we have to preventDefault of "submit" button.

Comment: I have added `?` symbol to check if event exist then preventDefault else do nothing.

Comment: If you not using those `size` and `elements` input inside form element you can remove `event?.preventDefault()` line. it will effect nothing.

Comment: if button in form element you have to call function like `<input type="submit" value="add value" onclick="addval(event)"`>` to prevent reloading page.

Comment: I think you don't need to use form element so you can remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `inputArray`, but it has no elements in it. You have to first populate it with items.

In this case, we can simplify the code by using the `Array` function to create an array with a certain number of items, and [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to set each item in the array to a specified value:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="screen-body-item">
    <div class="app-form">
      <div class="app-form-group">
        <input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter size" id="size">
        <input type="text" class="app-form-control" placeholder="enter element" id="ele">
        <input type="button" value="" value="add value" class="app-form-button" onclick="addval()">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    function addval() {
      let size = document.getElementById('size').value;
      let value = document.getElementById('ele').value;
      var inputArray = Array(+size).fill(value)
      console.log(inputArray)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```